# A class implementing common method of interface

Tags: java, interface

There is just one question in which  i am got confused...
There are two interfaces A , B which contains the same method methodC()...and C class implements A&B. which interface method it should be implemented A or B
Now as per my analysis i have lyk say below class..

```
 interface  A {
        /**
         * Doc A
         * **/
        public void MethodA();

        public String MethodB();

    }

    interface  B {
        /**
         * Doc B
         * **/
        public String MethodA();

        public void MethodB();
    }

    class lucy implements A,B{

        @Override
        public String MethodA() {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String MethodB() {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Hello
>   Hello

Comment: It won't compile. I don't know how you got that output.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well forgot the code since it is raw coded , major concern is concept

Comment: Again: this won't compile, that's why this question at all is strange. Test it.

Comment: does it matter? methods from A or B does not have implementations.

Comment: Yes it matters. Because if you test it, the compiler will give you the answer: you can't.

Comment: @user3875672 There has to be more here - there's is _absolutely no way_ the code you have posted could output "Hello Hello"

Comment: @user3875672 what concept? there is no such concept at all! at least in java!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have an interface:

```
public interface A {

    public void firstMethod();

    public void secondMethod();
}
```

and this interface:

```
public interface B {

    public void firstMethod();

    public void secondMethod();
}
```

If you make a class, that implements both of these interfaces, it will be compiled and work ok.

```
public class MyClass implements A, B {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void firstMethod() {
        // some code here
    }

    @Override
    public void secondMethod() {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

But if you add methods `firstMethod()` and `secondMethod()` to the `MyClass` but with different return type, it won't compile.

```
public class MyClass implements A, B {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    public String firstMethod() {
        return "";
    }

    public String secondMethod() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void firstMethod() {
        // some code here
    }

    @Override
    public void secondMethod() {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

To compose method signature Java uses method parameters, but not the return type. And it will lead to "method is already defined" error. Because from Java's point of view methods: `void firstMethod();` and `String firstMethod();` (the same for the `secondMethod()` method) have the same signatures.